# getting the ascii code of a sentence

Tags: python, ascii

I am trying to make a code that will give me the ascii code of a sentence, right now i can only give one letter

for example

```
a = input("c")

b = ord(a)

print (b)
```

it prints 99, my goal is to type abc with the outcome of 97 98 99

Comment: Loop through the input char by char...

Comment: Why python? [`od`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/od.1.html) is just made for that.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through `a`:

```
print([ord(c) for c in a])
```

Comment: Looks like the question is regarding Python 3.x :)

Comment: Python 3: `print(*(ord(c) for c in s))`